# Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-\sin(xt)}dt}{x}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$

Tags: integration, limits

Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-\sin(xt)}dt}{x}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$.

$e^{\sin(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{n}(x)}{n!}$ and $\int e^{\sin(x)}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int \frac{\sin^{n}(x)}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\int \sin^{n}(x)}{n!}$.

I also observed that by using $\sin(xt) \geq \frac{2xt}{\pi}$, then $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-\sin(xt)}dt \leq \frac{\pi}{2x}(1-\frac{1}{e^x})$. However I did not obtain something useful for proving this equality. Any help, please?

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: You can apply it and get the answer immediately as  $\int_0^{\pi/2} tdt$ which is equal to RHS.

Comment: Why has this question been savagely edited ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: OP has been self-vandalizing numerous questions for some reason. I have rolled-back five instances so far. (I initially goofed in rolling this one back, but it should be okay now.) I have raised a flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-\sin(xt)}dt}{x}$$.
Let $xt=u \implies x dt =du$, then
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{x\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{x\pi}{2}}e^{-\sin(u)}du}{x^2}\to 0/0$$.
Use L Hospital differentiate up and down by Lebnitz to get
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-\sin(\pi x/2)}
)}{2x}$$
Again by L Kospital, differentiating ip and dowm we ger we get\
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\pi}{4} e^{-\sin (\pi x/2)} \cos (\pi x/2) (\pi/2) =\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$

Answer (score -1):

The derivative of the numerator is $-\int_0^{\pi /2} e^{-\sin (xt)} (-t\cos (xt) )dt$ bt Chain Rule (and differentiation inside the integral which can be justified using an aplication of DCT). As $ x\to 0$ this tends to $\int_0^{\pi/2} tdt=\frac {\pi^{2}} 8$

Comment: The integral converges to $\int e^{0}dt=\frac {\pi} 2$. @AnatolDenicula

Comment: Yes, DCT is Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: The first term $\frac {\pi} 2$ is a constant  and its derivative is $0$. @AnatolDenicula

Comment: This Wikipedia [page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) along with the L'Hopital's rule can help.